traefik+metallb external ip stuck at pending
I am running a k3s cluster locally on ubuntu and have made a test deployment of traefik+metallb.
Here is the link to the tutorial I am following: https://technotim.live/posts/kube-traefik-cert-manager-le/#traefik
Here's my folder struture:
.
├── install.sh
├── metallb
│   ├── metallb.yaml
│   └── values.yaml
└── traefik
    ├── dashboard
    │   ├── ingress.yaml
    │   ├── middleware.yaml
    │   └── secret-dashboard.yaml
    ├── default-headers.yaml
    └── values.yaml

Here's what the the status of the services looks like after deployment:
| NAMESPACE   | NAME                    | TYPE          | CLUSTER-IP     | EXTERNAL-IP | PORT(S)                       | AGE | SELECTOR |
|-------------|-------------------------|---------------|----------------|-------------|-------------------------------|-----|----------|
| default     | kubernetes              | ClusterIP     | 10.43.0.1      | none      | 443/TCP                       | 70m | none   |
| kube-system | kube-dns                | ClusterIP     | 10.43.0.10     | none      | 53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP        | 69m | k8s-app=kube-dns |
| kube-system | metrics-server          | ClusterIP     | 10.43.160.178  | none      | 443/TCP                       | 69m | k8s-app=metrics-server |
| traefik     | metallb-webhook-service | ClusterIP     | 10.43.76.91    | none      | 443/TCP                       | 58m | app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=metallb,app.kubernetes.io/name=metallb |
| traefik     | traefik                 | LoadBalancer  | 10.43.203.185  | pending   | 6887:30092/TCP,6888:32664/TCP | 58m | app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik-traefik,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik |

Sharing files which I have added or modified, here's my metallb.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: traefik
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.240/28

Here's my metallb/values.yaml, same as default: https://github.com/metallb/metallb/blob/main/charts/metallb/values.yaml
Here's my traefik/values.yaml:
globalArguments:
  - "--global.sendanonymoususage=false"
  - "--global.checknewversion=false"

additionalArguments:
  - "--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true"
  - "--log.level=INFO"

deployment:
  enabled: true
  replicas: 1
  annotations: {}
  podAnnotations: {}
  additionalContainers: []
  initContainers: []

ports:
  web:
    exposedPort: 6887
    redirectTo:
      port: websecure
      priority: 10
  websecure:
    exposedPort: 6888
    tls:
      enabled: true

ingressRoute:
  dashboard:
    enabled: false

providers:
  kubernetesCRD:
    enabled: true
    ingressClass: traefik-external
    allowExternalNameServices: true
  kubernetesIngress:
    enabled: true
    allowExternalNameServices: true
    publishedService:
      enabled: false

rbac:
  enabled: true

service:
  enabled: true
  type: LoadBalancer
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  spec:
    loadBalancerIP: 192.168.0.245
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - 192.168.0.240/28
  externalIPs: []

Here's my install.sh:
helm upgrade --install --namespace=traefik metallb metallb/metallb --values=metallb/values.yaml
kubectl apply -f metallb/metallb.yaml

helm upgrade --install --namespace=traefik traefik traefik/traefik --values=traefik/values.yaml
kubectl apply -f traefik/default-headers.yaml
kubectl apply -f traefik/dashboard/secret-dashboard.yaml
kubectl apply -f traefik/dashboard/middleware.yaml
kubectl apply -f traefik/dashboard/ingress.yaml

The rest of the files are the same as in the tutorial. Also, I have enabled UPNP Igd on my router temporarily to allow applications to forward ports. Where am I going wrong with my deployment?
